# Installed mod_wsgi on Debian with Pip and got "undefined forkpty" Error

Tags: linux, debian, installation, apache-http-server, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install mod_wsgi on Raspbian Stretch Lite (which is based on Debian Stretch).

[Following the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi), I installed apache and mod_wsgi with:

```
sudo apt -y install apache2 apache2-dev
source ~/venv/bin/activate
pip3.6 install mod_wsgi
```

Everything looks good so far. To verify that the installation was successful, I ran

```
mod_wsgi-express start-server
```

But I got the error

`apache2 (mod_wsgi-express): Syntax error on line 159 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:1000/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so into server: /home/pi/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: forkpty`

So what did I do wrong?

The mod_wsgi documentation [has a section on the undefined forkpty error](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#undefined-forkpty-on-fedora-7), but it only applies to Fedora and building mod_wsgi from source.

In case it's important, I installed Python 3.6 with:

```
sudo apt -y install build-essential checkinstall libbz2-dev libc6-dev libgdbm-dev libncursesw5-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev openssl tk-dev zlib1g-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.6.5.tgz
cd Python-3.6.5
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
cd ..
sudo rm -r Python-3.6.5
rm Python-3.6.5.tgz
python3.6 -m venv ~/venv
source ~/venv/bin/activate
pip3.6 install --upgrade pip
pip3.6 install setuptools wheel
```

Answer (score 1):

## Workaround

I got it to work by installing from source. Note the **--with-python** option.

```
pip3.6 uninstall mod_wsgi
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.6.4.tar.gz
tar xzvf 4.6.4.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-4.6.4
./configure --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python3.6
make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo rm -r mod_wsgi-4.6.4
rm 4.6.4.tar.gz
echo "LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
echo "LogLevel wsgi:info" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.conf
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This doesn't provide the `mod_wsgi-express` command, but you do get a working installation.

## Other Notes

- As [mentioned here](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#undefined-forkpty-on-fedora-7), I tried adding `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libutil.so` to the end of /etc/apache2/envvars, but this fix didn't work.
- Using `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` will only work with Python 3.5, not 3.6.